# Access denied at root site collection

Tags: permissions

I seem not to understand the groups MS has added Sharepoint 2010 root sites.

On my production I have simply added an AD Group(All staff) and I have given them read permission.
Which means they should have basically read access to site,lists etc..
But when user logs in the get access denied.

These groups "Restricted Readers and Style Resource Readers are just confusing.
Can anyone help or been through this as users need to get acesss.

Answer (score 2):

Have all resources that may affect the home page been checked in/published as a major version/approved? This could be anything from a CSS file, javascript, master page, or page layout.

If you've verified that users have been granted access by checking the effective permissions link, then this is your culprit.

Comment: Thanks 
I did check that and there all approved.One thing i had to do to get it working is to put the AD group under the Site visitors SP group:) 
It won't work if the AD Group is applied directly.

Comment: I had this problem because a custom master page I had copied over to the new site collection was in a pending state. Thanks.